# When the image is fully loaded, then show the form else wait

Tags: jquery

I have background image 1280x720 png, there i have lot of buttons, when one button is pressed then it change the image of spmain and it maps to other buttons.

Now the problem is my map buttons appear first before the new image is loaded.

Following is my code:

```
function button_3b2_form1_submit() {
  console.log(">>> Button: button_3b2_form1_submit" ,  selected_logo , selected_language);
  $('#spmain').attr('src', 'images/OwnagePranks/rakesh/Hippity Hoppitus.Some Budy.png');
  $('#spmain').attr('usemap', 'map_to_the_form');

  $('#map_to_the_form').show(); // show this only when  Hippity Hoppitus.Some Budy.png is fully loaded

}
```

How can i wait for this line to be sure its fully loaded?

```
$('#spmain').attr('src', 'images/OwnagePranks/rakesh/Hippity Hoppitus.Some Budy.png');
```

and then move to next?

Comment: You can make use of `load` event that triggers when the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `#spmain` element is an `img`, then you can attach a handler to the `load()` event to run some code when the image has fully loaded. Try this:

```
function button_3b2_form1_submit() {
    $('#spmain').attr({
        'src': 'images/OwnagePranks/rakesh/Hippity Hoppitus.Some Budy.png',
        'usemap': 'map_to_the_form'
    });
}

// attach this in the document.ready handler:
$('#spmain').load(function() {
    $('#map_to_the_form').show();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't we need to bind the `load` event before setting the `src` attribute for image?

Comment: @mohamedrias that's right - which is why it should be done only once on DOMReady. Repeatedly attaching the event handler on each successive click is redundant.

Comment: Great. But in this scenario, since the `$('#spmain')` is an image, it would trigger the onload function before itself, so the form would be visible. Hope in the load function need to check for the image URL before showing the form in that case. Whether it's new image or old one.

Comment: Problem is form should be visible only when the images are fully loaded. (i have 100 maps and 100 forms, each form loads after 1280x720 image is fully loaded) using the .load in .ready is working for first time but not for next time..

Comment: Example: Logo menu, you select logo it loads a image asking which language, you select language its asking now a new menu screen with form1. now i just want image fully gets loaded and then actions can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#spmain" ).load(function() {
  //Your logic
});
```

Assuming #spmain is an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `onload` event to the image and then set the `src` attribute.

So once the image has loaded in the onload function, show the form.

```
 $('#spmain').load(function() {
          $('#map_to_the_form').show(); 
    }).attr('src', 'images/OwnagePranks/rakesh/Hippity Hoppitus.Some Budy.png');
```